# How to get the selected value in selectOneRadio with JSF

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, selectoneradio

my question is that simple. How to get the selected value in a  mark in a Bean with JSF ?

I have this simple form, which works but I didn't find how to get the value of the user choice.

Can someone help ?

Here is the form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        Question :
        <h:form id="questionForm">

            <h:outputLabel
                value="#{questionBean.questions[questionBean.counter].askedQuestion}">
            </h:outputLabel>

            <h:selectOneRadio>
                <f:selectItems value="#{questionBean.questions[questionBean.counter].proposals}"
                    var="proposal" itemValue="#{proposal}" />
            </h:selectOneRadio>

            <h:link value="Question suivante" outcome="index.xhtml"/>

            <f:metadata>
                <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{questionBean.counter}" />
                <f:viewAction action="#{questionBean.increment()}" />
            </f:metadata>

        </h:form>

    </h:body>
    </html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How to get the selected value of a "selectOneRadio" mark in a Bean with JSF ?*

Comment: If found it :<h:selectOneRadio valueChangeListener="#{questionBean.selectQuestion}">

Comment: public void selectQuestion(ValueChangeEvent event){
  selectedQuestion = (String) event.getNewValue();
  System.out.println("selected = " + selectedQuestion);

 }